# How to find the client name who has logged in to machine?

Tags: batch-file, powershell, logging, cmd

We are trying to find from which machine a user has taken rdp .

Using "quser" utility we are able to get all the information about logged in user except client name.

Following is the command

```
function Get-LoggedOnUser
{
  param([String[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME)

    $ComputerName | ForEach-Object {
      (quser /SERVER:$_) -replace '\s{2,}', ',' | 
        ConvertFrom-CSV |
        Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerName -Value $_ -PassThru
  }
}
```

It displays all the information which can be provided in Windows task manager except client Name .

[image]

How to get client Name using powershell?

Comment: does `$env:CLIENTNAME` works for you? `quser` seems doesn't include the client name information

Comment: @poiu2000 Is it possible to run $env:ClientName in remote machine via remoting?

Comment: There is no $env:ClientName. Did you mean $env:ComputerName? Yes, it will be available in the remote session.

Comment: @Samselvaprabu Take a look here: http://www.myotherpcisacloud.com/post/2013/01/13/Getting-RDP-Sessions-with-Client-Computer-Name.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if WMI has a way to do this. You can check the PSTerminal Services module and it has a `Get-TSSession` cmdlet which does the same job you are looking for.

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/PSTerminalServices

This module uses binary [Cassia namespace.](https://code.google.com/p/cassia/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/0e43993a-895a-4afe-a2b2-045a5146048a
```

and look for the logged on user with a logon type of RemoteInteractive

Answer (score 0):

You can read that information from the Security eventlog (look for logon type 10):

```psh
$username = '...'
$eventID  = 4624    # 526 on Server 2003 and earlier
$date     = (Get-Date).Date

$pattern  = 'logon type:\s+10[\s\S]+source network address:\s+(\S+)'

Get-EventLog Security -InstanceId $eventID -EntryType SuccessAudit `
    -After $date -Message '*$username*' `
  | ? { $_.Message -match $pattern } `
  | % { $matches[1] } `
  | select -Unique
```

Note that on Server 2003 and earlier you need to check for event ID 528 instead of 4624.

**References:**

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787567
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977519